# Mount More Space Under /

Tags: debian, hard-disk, disk-usage

I am trying to install a package and apt complains of not enough space at `/var/cache/apt/archives`.

The usual commands:

```shell
apt-get autoclean
apt-get autoremove
```

do not work. Turns out because most of the disks space are mounted under `/run`, `/run/user/0`, `/dev`, `/dev/shm`

```shellsession
root@prox:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G     0   16G   0% /dev <<<<<
tmpfs           3.2G  872K  3.2G   1% /run <<<<<
/dev/md0        3.6G  3.2G  258M  93% /
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm <<<<<
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/0 <<<<<
```

It should be a 2 step process, right?

1. Decrease the space taken up by `/dev`, say to 10G
2. Allocate the 6G to `/dev/md0`

What settings/config should I make to achieve that? I am using Debian 11

Comment: you are a) totally misunderstanding what a mount is, and b) totally misunderstanding what /dev/, /run, etc are. These do not take a single byte away from your / filesystem.

Comment: I don't think it would be wrong to educate the poster a little more. All these filesystems, apart from /dev/md0, reside in RAM. Your option is to either increase /dev/md0 (since I don't know anything about this block device, I can't tell you if this is possible and how), or remove unused files. Perhaps the output of the `lsblk` command helps understanding your block device situation; add it to the question.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thanks for reminding me about the /dev folder. I read this a long time ago about /dev not taking up any space. This machine is a bare metal it is supposed to have 960G of hard disk space but quite shocked when it complains of not having enough space while updating. Seems like it is a malfunction bare metal, the RAID would sometime work.

Comment: @gnulab To me it looks like an error at system initialization. You have a root filesystem with less than 4GB; somebody or something must have decided to set it up this way.

Comment: @berndbausch Perhaps whoever set it up did so a few decades ago when 4G would've been more than enough for a relatively light system. Alternately, they were going to include disks for `/usr/`, `/var/`, `/home/` and `/tmp/` and just forgot.

Comment: cat /proc/mdstat, cat /proc/partitions, lsblk etc. to check where those supposed 960G of HDD space went

Answer (score 0):

`/run` resides in RAM, and does not eat away your disk space. Quoting [from the FHS document](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0):

> This directory contains system information data describing the system since it was booted. Files under this directory must be cleared (removed or truncated as appropriate) at the beginning of the boot process.

`/dev` does not take up space neither, because it's where devices are mounted. Quoting from the same source:

> The `/dev` directory is the location of special or device files.

Your root filesystem is less than 4 Gb.  What you need to do is to check why your 960 Gb hard disk is not recognized; verify that it is correctly connected, formatted, and mounted. Some commands that can help you are `lsblk`, `fdisk`, `mount`, `cat /etc/fstab`.